# How can I reinstall Windows Defender on my Windows 7 operating system

Tags: windows, installation, security, windows-defender

How do I reinstall Windows Defender to my Windows 7 Professional. It kept crashing, so I uninstalled it (And it DOES uninstall!) with the idea of reinstalling it.

But when I try to reinstall, the program insists that I already have it, and cancels the reinstall! It appears listed on my computer, but when I try to start it, the program says, correctly

> Windows Defender does not exist as an installed service.

Nonetheless, when I try to reinstall, the install program insists that it will not install, on the grounds that the program is already there. But it is not. Is there any way I can reinstall it?

Answer (score 3):

See if it will install from this page

http://www.microsoft.com/windows/products/winfamily/defender/default.mspx

[If you install MSE,](http://www.microsoft.com/security/pc-security/mse.aspx) it will disable Defender and take over the role it plays. Defender is an outdated product.

Be sure to uninstall any other Anti Virus you have installed Before installing MSE.

Comment: Yeah, get MSE.  It's 1000 better.